# data from web server becomes null when accessed in iOs 5

Tags: iphone

I have an app that gets a web addess (link) from a web server and displays it in my MFMailComposeViewController class. On iOs 4 the web address is visible but on iOs 5 sometimes the web Address is null and the link is not working but sometimes it has the link working. Can anyone please suggest what needs to be done? Thanks.

I placed this code in the body of the MFMailComposeViewController

```
[body appendString: @"Use your Computer Browser <a href=\""];
[body appendString: self.myContact.webAddress];
```

Comment: show the code where you are getting the web address and passing it along to MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: I placed this code in the body of the MFMailComposeViewController -  [body appendString:@"Use your Computer Browser  <a href=\""];
    [body appendString:self.myContact.webAddress];

Comment: In iOs5 the webAddress sometimes returns null..but in iOs 4 it works just fine.

Comment: Do an NSLog first on self.myContact.webAddress

Comment: I agree with Terenta... please edit your original question to show a bit more code.  The one line up there in your comment doesn't give much to work with.

Comment: webAddress is the link from the webserver... i placed it in the body of my MFMailComposeViewController..in iOs4 the link is working correctly but in iOs5 sometimes the link returns a null string..

Answer (score 0):

Do you also include this line of code:

```
[body appendString: "\">text of link goes here</a>"];
```

?  If not, then you have a bad link and the fact that it works in iOS 4 is something of a bug.

In general, whatever the problem is, my guess is that iOS 5 tightened up restrictions on bad HTML and no longer deals with invalid things that may have slipped-by in iOS 4.  Try this:

```
NSLog(@"Body: %@", body);
```

and make sure that your HTML is valid and what you expect.